# How to remove entire list but left only last index

Tags: java, android, string, list, arraylist

I'm in condition that requires 1 list to be always filled one by one and I want to delete the entire list but left it with only last index

I've been trying with these snippets. But it delete the entire row one by one

```
 int totalListPeriodeClick   = listPeriodeClick.size();

    if(listPeriodeClick.size() == 0) {
        listPeriodeClick.add("2019-04-30");
    } else if (listPeriodeClick.size() == 1) {

    } else if (listPeriodeClick.size() > 1){

        for (int i = 0; i < totalListPeriodeClick; i++){
            listPeriodeClick.remove(0);
        }
            setListPeriodeClickString(listPeriodeClick.get(0));
    }
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalListPeriodeClick; i++){
            listPeriodeClick.remove(0);
        }
```

and I want to get last index which will be had 0-index as list.get(0) by this code

```
setListPeriodeClickString(listPeriodeClick.get(0));
```

How it can be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not:

```
if (! listPeriodeClick.isEmpty()) {
  PeriodeClick last = listPeriodeClick.get(listPeriodeClick.size()-1);
  listPeriodeClick.clear();
  listPeriodeClick.add(last);
}
```

There is really no point in manually iterating a (potentially large) list just to remove elements. Remember the last entry, throw away *everything*, and re-add that last entry. If you want to save another method call, use

```
int size = listPeriodeClick.size();
if (size > 1) { ...
```